# Chrome extension to display message on click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to make an extension that displays a message about a character when I e.g. ctrl+click/hover on that character.

I develop desktop software and can get a basic "hello world" going from the docs, but I can't see how I can respond to a ctrl+click/hover on a character - I know I must be able to as e.g. [yomitan](https://github.com/themoeway/yomitan) does (but shift+hover), I want essentially that functionality but much simpler (only looking up the character underneath the cursor, and displaying one word associated with it).

Can anyone outline the steps I might take to do this? I don't really care where the message is, but a frame at the cursor position (that e.g. goes away when clicked) would be fine.

Comment: You need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) with a listener for `click` and `mouseover` events, not an action popup. You'll use standard DOM methods to show the info and change its appearance via CSS in the style attribute or in ShadowDOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, I think I can follow that, except how do I get at the DOM methods?

Comment: By using DOM e.g. document.createElement and so on. There are many tutorials.